# refresh the page after ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, ajaxform

This script is part of my site, why not refresh the page?

I tested other methods available on the stackoverflow but
did not answer.

Help me, thanks

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#loginform").on('submit',(function(e) {

    var show_result_ajax = $("#show-result-ajax-loginform");

        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "inc/custom/login.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data)
            {

                if(data != 'empty_error'){
                   show_result_ajax.fadeOut(function(){
                          show_result_ajax.html(data);
                   });
                   show_result_ajax.fadeIn();
                }
                else
                if(data == 'empty_error'){
                    window.location.reload();
                }


            }
        });
    }
));

});
```

Comment: what ajax returns ?

Comment: Hi Mohammad, Does the data provide your expression? Have you checked it with console log?

Comment: Hi @KamuranSönecek, yes

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#loginform").on('submit',(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var show_result_ajax = $("#show-result-ajax-loginform");

        $.ajax({
            url: "inc/custom/login.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data)
            {
                if(data != 'empty_error'){
                    show_result_ajax.fadeOut(function(){
                        show_result_ajax.html(data);
                    });
                    show_result_ajax.fadeIn();
                }
                else if(data == 'empty_error'){
                    location.reload();
                }
            }
        });

        return false;
    }));

});
```

Comment: WOW, I found my problem.

Comment: My issues from data ajax request!